# Tunable block (arrow through it)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing

How can I draw a tunable block in TikZ (one that displays an arrow through it)?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\node (a) {}; \draw ([shift=(-120:20pt)]a.-120) -- (a.-120); \draw [->] (a.60) -- +(60:20pt);` Obviously untested as nothing to test with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible, very simple solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}     
        \draw[-Triangle,very thick] (-6pt, -22pt) -- (6pt, 22pt);
        \draw[very thick, fill=white] (-12pt, -12pt) rectangle (10pt, 10pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]